# Transitioning between two different geom_smooth() objects in gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm having difficulty with gganimate and I'd be grateful for some help.

I'm interested in how the relationship between two continuous variables differs across two values of a factor variable. Imagine, say, I'm interested in how the relationship between test scores and height varies before and after a given intervention. My data has roughly the following structure:

```
set.seed(24601)

height <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)

test_data <- 
  tibble(height = rep(height, 2),
         test_scores = rnorm(20, 0, 1),
         before_or_after = c(rep("before", 10), rep("after", 10)),
         id = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), 2))
```

If I wanted to show this in a static ggplot, I could do this:

```
ggplot(data = test_data) +
  aes(x = height,
      y = test_scores,
      colour = before_or_after) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

but I'm interested in drawing attention to the variation in test scores before and after the intervention, and so wanting to animate each observation and the geom_smooth().

I can animate each observation as follows:

```
ggplot(data = test_data) +
  aes(x = height,
      y = test_scores,
      group = id) +
  geom_point() +
  transition_states(before_or_after)
```

but ideally I'd do something like the below:

```
ggplot(data = test_data) +
  aes(x = height,
      y = test_scores,
      group = id) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
              se = FALSE) +
  transition_states(before_or_after)
```

with the geom_smooth moving alongside the points. However, when I do so, I get the error message

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "group", value = "") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

If anyone can advise how I can resolve this, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Use `transition_manual(before_or_after)` in your program instead of `transition_states(before_or_after)`.  Then you get the following output:

[image: output]

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have the points and the geom_smooths move between states, rather than just the two stills as shown here? Something like the above example with transition_states(before_or_after) where the points are moving up and down, but with the geom_smooths moving up and down as well.

Comment: I am not sure as `geom_smooth` is a static representation of the points at the end of those states.